# Left textarea and Google translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can Google Translate highlight text in the left-hand side window on the Google Translate web: http://translate.google.com/ ?

On the right-hand side the text is rendered as `spans`, but how do the achieve that in the `textarea` on the left?

Comment: The highlighting isn't actually in the textarea... It's an element painted over the textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually you cannot highlight content inside text area, however you can do this by painting on the background of textarea. there is a small jquery component which does the highilighting might be of help to you

http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/